# Is it necessary to antisymmetrize the products of components in a product of differential forms in order to get the components of the product form?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Hopefully all of the evil things Mathematica's LaTeX conversion tool did to my expressions.  I should warn the reader that Mozilla is not rendering this correctly for me.

In an effort to understand the component definition given by Ciufolini
and Wheeler in [Gravitation and Inertia](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691033235/gravitation-and-inertia) of the exterior product

\begin{align*}
\alpha_{a_{1}\ldots a_{p+q}} & =\left(\tilde{\theta}\wedge\tilde{\omega}\right)_{a_{1}\ldots a_{p+q}}=\frac{\left(p+q\right)!}{p!q!}\theta_{\left[a_{1}\ldots a_{p}\right.}\omega_{\left.a_{p+1}\ldots a_{p+q}\right]}
\end{align*}

I created the following example:

\begin{align*}
\theta_{ij} & =\theta_{[ij]},\\
\omega_{ijk} & =\omega_{[ijk],}\\
\tilde{\theta} & =\frac{1}{2}\theta_{[ij]}d\mathit{x}^{i}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{j},\\
\tilde{\omega} & =\frac{1}{6}\omega_{[ijk]}d\mathit{x}^{i}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{j}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{k},\\
\tilde{\alpha} & =\tilde{\theta}\wedge\tilde{\omega},\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{6}\theta_{ab}\omega_{cde}d\mathit{x}^{a}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{b}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{c}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{d}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{e}\\
 & =\frac{1}{\left(2+3\right)!}\alpha_{abcde}d\mathit{x}^{a}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{b}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{c}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{d}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{e},\\
\alpha_{abcde} & =\frac{6!}{12}\theta_{[ab}\omega_{cde]}.
\end{align*}

**This is my question: would it be incorrect to write**

\begin{align*}
\alpha_{abcde} & =\frac{6!}{12}\theta_{ab}\omega_{cde},
\end{align*}

**because there's nothing in the simple product of scalar components
to ensure we have**

\begin{align*}
\theta_{ab}\omega_{cde} & =-\theta_{ac}\omega_{bde}?
\end{align*}

I'm confident that a proper p-form will have the same meaning when
expressed on a standard tensor basis. That is, assuming $\tilde{\alpha}$
to be a 5-form, we have

\begin{align*}
\tilde{\alpha} & =\alpha_{abcde}d\mathit{x}^{a}\otimes d\mathit{x}^{b}\otimes d\mathit{x}^{c}\otimes d\mathit{x}^{d}\otimes d\mathit{x}^{e}\\
 & =\frac{1}{5!}\alpha_{abcde}d\mathit{x}^{a}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{b}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{c}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{d}\wedge d\mathit{x}^{e}
\end{align*}

That's because the components already have the property $\alpha_{abcde}=\alpha_{\left[abcde\right]}.$
When either expression of the tensor acts on an argument list of five
vectors, it will produce the alternating sum of the tensor product
components, which is the definition of the determinant. That is built
into the wedge product basis, but not into the tensor product basis.
So, for the two expressions to behave identically, the components
have to be antisymmetric.

Comment: Where did $6!$ come from? And what precisely do you mean when you write $\alpha_{a\dots z}=\alpha_{[a\dots z]}$?

Comment: Indices aren't restricted to increasing, so we need to divide by 3!.  [i...j] means antisymmetrized. https://handwiki.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor

Comment: I know what the symbol means. It means to sum over all permutations, with signs. So do you mean it when you write what I typed? No. And you did not explain the $6!$ in the final formulas.

Comment: The $\alpha_{a\dots z}=\alpha_{[a\dots z]}$ means the components equal the result of applying antisymmetrization.  That is, the tensor is antisymmetric.  It's probably wrong to have the 1/3! on the tensor basis expression.  I need to think that through. And I'm too tired to do that right now.  I'm confident that I still need it for the p-form bases.